# Unable to compile .proto files for Tensorflow object-detection API

Tags: python, protoc

I'm trying to install Tensorflow and im having trouble compiling the .proto files.

I try running this command in the research folder:
C:/protoc/bin/protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

but it outputs:
object_detection/protos/*.proto: No such file or directory

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, it is cumbersome.
It works if i compile them one by one.

e.g.
C:/protoc/bin/protoc object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto --python_out=.

Where C:/protoc/bin/protoc is the path to protoc.exe file

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, try it

```
protoc-3.4.0-win32\bin\protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

`protoc-3.4.0-win32\bin\protoc` is path to protoc.exe file