# Compiling Protocol Buffers Tensorflow Object Detection API on Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I'm brand new to the Windows environment and have spent several hours trying to install Tensorflow with the object detection tutorial.  I've read dozens of threads and seen several videos and have no luck.

Here's where I am at:  I have all the Tensorflow dependencies installed and the protoc (version 3.7) executable, but when I run the line `object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.` I get a `no such file or directory` error.

Here is what I am running from the command line, from the models directory:

`D:\training\Tensorflow\protoc\bin\protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`

I've also tried `D:\training\Tensorflow\protoc\bin\protoc research/object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.` since the path from my current directory (models) to the proto files is `research/object_detection/protos/`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55344103/unable-to-compile-proto-files-for-tensorflow-object-detection-api) thread suggests compiling each .proto file one by one, and after trying to compile the first with `D:\training\Tensorflow\protoc\bin\protoc research/object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto --python_out=.`

I get this error:

```
object_detection/protos/grid_anchor_generator.proto: File not found.
object_detection/protos/ssd_anchor_generator.proto: File not found.
object_detection/protos/multiscale_anchor_generator.proto: File not found.
research/object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto: Import "object_detection/protos/grid_anchor_generator.proto" was not found or had errors.
research/object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto: Import "object_detection/protos/ssd_anchor_generator.proto" was not found or had errors.
research/object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto: Import "object_detection/protos/multiscale_anchor_generator.proto" was not found or had errors.
research/object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto:13:5: "GridAnchorGenerator" is not defined.
research/object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto:14:5: "SsdAnchorGenerator" is not defined.
research/object_detection/protos/anchor_generator.proto:15:5: "MultiscaleAnchorGenerator" is not defined.
```

Those other .proto files are in fact in the same directory, so I'm not sure why it's not finding them.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the command from `research` directory. As specified [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#protobuf-compilation).

```
# From tensorflow/models/research/
D:\training\Tensorflow\protoc\bin\protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```